# No network access with Ubuntu on Vmware

Tags: linux, vmware

I am trying to get a Ubuntu virtual machine to connect to my network. I have set a static IP address but I cannot get any communication with the network. I have installed VMWare Tools. The network card is set to bridged networking.

- I am running Ubuntu version 8.10 Intrepid
- The Vmware version is Vmware workstation version 10
- Other virtual machines have access to the network and my host.
- Another Linux virtual machine Kali Linux is working fine with
  networking.
- Ping to my gateway just gives destination host unreachable.
- I have tried removing the virtual network card and adding it back in.

**Interfaces**

[image]

**Ifconfig**

[image]

Comment: Silly me I was running the wrong command to get the interface up, should be sudo ifup eth4

Comment: This means you've got it fixed?

Comment: Yes I got it all fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use `sudo ifup eth4` and not `sudo ifconfig eth4 up`.